# Google VR SDK and Google Plus SDK - Conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-vr

We are integrating `Google VR` SDK (0.8.0) with an existing is application. This existing application has `Google Plus` SDK (1.7.1) implementation.

When we try to include the `VR` SDK, there seems to be some conflict. If we remove `Google Plus` SDK everything works fine.

We are getting linker error as duplicate symbol

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
>       /Users/Guest/DemoApp/Pods/googleplus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMLogger.o)
>       /Users/Guest/DemoApp/Vendor/GVRSDKLib/libCardboardSDK.a(GTMLogger_c2914cc749638ce6e1e23d5f18c86798.o)
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
>       /Users/Guest/DemoApp/Pods/googleplus-ios-sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMLogger.o)
>       /Users/Guest/DemoApp/Vendor/GVRSDKLib/libCardboardSDK.a(GTMLogger_c2914cc749638ce6e1e23d5f18c86798.o)

Can we get some direction on how we can proceed further, it is important for us to have both the SDKs available.

Comment: any update on this one ?